Bluetooth pairing with a device no longer working, device appears on pairing screen but clicking it does nothing
My Google Pixel 4 cellphone (Android 13 build TP1A.221005.002.B2, up to date) stopped pairing with headphones (Shokz Open Air Pro) after working fine for a few years. This happened after I paired the headphones with a new phone, then later tried connected my usual phone with the headphones and it wouldn't work as they usual did, so I had my usual phone forget the headphones and try to re-pair. That's when the problem arose, not pairing or responding to clicks on the pairing list.
To try and fix this, I had already had my phone forget the BT connection, so I tried to reset the headphones and tried what I could with limited settings there. Starting fresh should work since it worked before, I figured. One of the only other options for headphones other than factory resetting was to enable [multipoint pairing][1], I tried enabling that too and I don't think it had any effect, I've again reset the headphones. The furthest I've got is the headphones show up on my phone when trying to pair with new devices, but when I click the headphones, the phone doesn't respond.
I tested my phone and the headphones independently. My phone connects with other BT devices no problem. They show up on list available for pairing, I click them, it says connecting and does its thing on both ends, data and sound transfers fine. I tested the headphones with two other phones and a computer, and they all work fine, connecting as expected.
Something between my phone and the headphones appears stuck, such that my phone is unresponsive to the request to pair with the headphones, despite recognizing them as available for pairing. The headphones are in pairing mode and can connect with other devices from there, so as far as I can tell, nothing is wrong on that end.
So far on my phone, I tried:

toggling Bluetooth on and off,
forgetting the headphones in the first place (they haven't paired to let me try to 'forget' again)
I turned on developer mode and toggled "Disable Bluetooth A2DP hardware offload" to turn it on. I saw this resolved some BT issues for other users, but no effect for me. I turned it back off.
I've restarted the phone many times throughout all this, tried over a couple of weeks now.

What other settings can I adjust on my phone to try to reset/remedy pairing with these headphones? Is there a way to reset my phone's BT completely? I have a few other paired devices I'd rather not forget if unnecessary but I can reset and reconnect to all those if that might fix these headphones. I just don't want to factory reset the phone if I can avoid it.
[1]: https://help.shokz.com/s/article/Multipoint-Pairing

After posting this I figured out an answer - in settings, searching for reset options, I found an option to reset wireless connections, mobile data, and bluetooth. I tried that and it fixed this problem - now in the pairing menu, clicking the headphones actually connected. Other devices are also connecting. That's a relief! Posting here in case anyone else has this issue.
